# ffmpeg in worker role wont close the window

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-worker-roles

I am trying the below code in the worker role, but the issue i feel in

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/anton_staykov/archive/2010/10/08/convert-video-files-in-windows-azure-using-ffmpeg.aspx

exeProcess.WaitForExit(); line, it pops up windows which wont close on its won, when i close it manually then it will move to the next line. when the FFMPEG operation is done it should close on its won and move to next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why at all you see the pops up window. You probably miss any of these settings:

```
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.ErrorDialog = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

They are all required to suppress poping out of any and all windows and are all required.
If you use the code as provided with all the setting there should not be a command window. The code is really old and, the blog post you refer has small issue. When we want to take everything by code should also explicitly state that we are not redirecting StandardInput. The code from refereed blog post:

```
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

is changed into:

```
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

in the Upgrade branch of the source code: https://azurevideoconv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CloudFFMpeg-upgrade/VideoProcessor/VideoConverter.cs

In any case, I haven't updated this since years, as there is Windows Azure Media services now. If you take the way to using ffmpeg, make sure you use the 32bit compiled executable! I always had issues running the 64bit one.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply
i have couple of question
1. exeProcess.WaitForExit(); if i am using this line, then it will pops up the window which i need it to close manually because the ffmpeg.exe wont be aware of the when the command is executed. I am running this on windows - 7 64 bit machines. when i put in the cloud  which is windows server 2012 i am not sure what happens there
2. FFMPEG how to make it to read the private container
3. Currently i m giving the out put as local path if i want to store the output directly on the cloud how i m going to do

Comment: any video link which explain the code you have written code